# OpenX 2.8.10 banner for Joomla 3.0

Tags: javascript, banner, openx, joomla3.0

What is the best component in Joomla 3.0 to put ads created by OpenX AdServer? The JavaScript code generated in OpenX AdServer is not working with the default component of banner. I am in development phase using a [Jumi component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/1023) to place the JavaScript code.

Do you know any component to place several banners (JavaScript Tag, iFrame Tag) in the same view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

iframes are required if you want the ads to autorefresh properly.  There is a [plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/ads-a-affiliates/affiliate-systems/affiliate-advertising/12297) that I haven't tried that says it integrates well with Joomla 2.5.